# Get all elements in the view of iphone app using xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to take screenshot of every screen during iphone app automation on a simulator. Along with the screenshot I also want to extract all strings in the that particular view before taking a screenshot using xcode. Is there a way to do that? Purpose is to send these screenshots and strings for validation to another tool.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Web Driver Agent(WDA) provided by facebook. It does provide all the functionalities you need for your app.

Here is link to github repo for it:

https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent

Please have a look at it. It might help you achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the XCUITest framework for your automation, you can use `XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()` to get a screenshot of the current state.

To fetch all text currently on screen you can use `XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .textField)` or `.buttons` or `.any` or whatever you expect to be on the screen, and extract the text from the element

```
let descendants = XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .textField)
foreach descendant in descendants { descendant.label /*do something*/ }
```

You need to set an Accessibility Identifier on the view elements for this to work.